# Find a non-abelian example of subgroups satisfying direct sum properties

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, direct-sum

**I would like to understand the following result**:

> Let $G$ be a group and $A_1, A_2 \subseteq G$ be subgroups satisfying the following conditions
>
> (a) For all $g \in G$ there are elements $h_1 \in A_1$ and $h_2 \in A_2$ such that $g=h_1 h_2$.
>
> (b) $A_1 \cap A_2 = \{ e \}$
>
> (c) For all $h_1 \in A_1$ and $h_2 \in A_2$ we have $h_1 h_2 = h_2 h_1$.
>
> Then $G$ is isomorphic to $A_1 \times A_2$.

In order to understand this result, I am trying to find some examples of subgroups satisfying this property.

**My examples**:

1. If $G = A_1$ and $A_2 = \{ e \}$, the properties are obviously satisfied.
2. If $V$ is a vectorspace and $G = (V,+)$ and $A_1,A_2$ are two subspaces of $V$ satisfying $V = A_1 \oplus A_2$ (in the context of direct sums of vector spaces), then these properties are also satisfied.

However, I am not happy with my found examples yet. **I would like have an example where**

- $G$ is a non-abelian group and
- where neither $A_1$ nor $A_2$ is the trivial group.

Could you please help me finding such an example? Thank you very much!

Comment: You can make examples in a trivial way: if $X,Y$ are any two groups then with $G=X\times Y$, $A=X\times\{1\}$, $B=\{1\}\times Y$ you have an example. But presumably that's cheating?

Comment: @ancientmathematician: Although to say that it's cheating is a little harsh, since the content of the theorem in question is that every example arises in the manner you have described (at least up to isomorphism).

Comment: But that does raise an interesting issue for the OP to address: What other kind of answer would be acceptable to this problem?

Comment: I thought there is a more fancy example (i.e. without the cartesian product or the trivial subgroup involved somewhere) but did not see that each example can be classified that way.